# Have two attributes have the same value between entities with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Sorry for the noob question. I have this:

[image: Core Data Setup]

Now, the `Item` entities has `dateCreated` and `title` and I want those two attributes on `ItemDetails` to be the same.
`Item` would create these two attributes, so `ItemDetails` has to grab that data.

`ItemDetails` has a view controller that should display these attributes.

The question of it all is:

How do I make `ItemDetails's` attributes have the same data (or be the same object or w/e) of `Item's` attributes?

Comment: This seems a strange design. Why is ItemDetails a separate class rather than just part of Item?

Answer (score 1):

Do not add dateCreated or title directly to the model for ItemDetails. In code, add computed properties that return `parentItem.dateCreated` and `parentItem.title`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the `dateCreated` and `title` are properties of the `Item` so your model should reflect that. You don't need the `ItemDetails` entity and your `Item` entity should be something like this:

```
extension Item {
    @NSManaged var dateCreated: Date
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

Then, for your view controller that will display these details, you'll do something like this:

```
let item = <your item>

dateLabel.text = item.date
title.text = item.title
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, you do understand me correctly! First, the extension part, do I put it in the new view controller swift file? Second, I put 

let item = [Items]()
        
daysLabel.text = item.dateCreated

But it says [Items] has no member 'dateCreated'

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just chose to use that to show you the properties of your Item entity instead of a picture of your model. The extension is a file on its own and is something you should have created when you created your model. Remember how you selected your `.xcdatamodeld` and created your entities? The next step is usually to tell Xcode to create your NSManagedObject subclasses (Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...) If you did this, you should have two files for your Item entity; `Item.swift` and `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift`. The `+CoreDataProperties` file is the one that contains the extension.